# Group made of $\begin{pmatrix} a &b \\ c & d \\ \end{pmatrix}$ where $ad-bc\not=0,a,b,c,d\in \mathbb Z_3$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, proof-explanation, determinant, finite-fields

I have very straightforward easy question, but I could not figure it out.

You are given a group $\left( \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}     a &b  \\     c & d  \\     \end{pmatrix}\;\big|\;ad-bc\not=0,a,b,c,d\in \mathbb Z_3 \right \},Matrix\; Multiplication \right)$

***Question:*** Show that $|G|=48$

***Given answer:***
[image]

I do not get the red underlined sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlined sentence means that we must exclude the three cases $(c,d) \neq \lambda (a,b)$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}_3 = \{0,1,2\}$.

- If we would have $(c,d) = \lambda (a,b)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}_3$, then we would get $ad - bc = a(\lambda b) - b (\lambda a) = 0$, meaning that the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & b  \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ is not in the set.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is a matrix with two rows and two columns, $\det A=0$ if and only if one of the rows is a multiple of the other one.

Comment: what about $n\times n$ cases, $det A=0$ iff they are mutually(or co-) relatively prime?

Answer (score 1):

If the second row is a multiple of the first row, say that $c=ka$ and $d=kb$, then $ad-bc=abk-bak=0$.